# How to avoid showing gofmt fail error when saving go code every time in Emacs

Tags: spacemacs, golang

Using Spacemacs and its go layer.

Using `Tramp` in Emacs ssh to remote server to edit go file. After saving the file, it will check the syntax with `gofmt` . But every time it shows the error below:

[image]

I have tried install these packages at localhost as official guide:

```
go get -u -v github.com/nsf/gocode
go get -u -v github.com/rogpeppe/godef
go get -u -v golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru
go get -u -v golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename
go get -u -v golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports

go get -u -v github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter
gometalinter --install --update
```

> https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Blang/go

Also set `(go :variables go-use-gometalinter t)`(or `(setq gofmt-command "goimports")`) in the `~/.spacemacs` file. But not work. Indeed, there aren't go runtime at remote server where go source exist.
So where it looking for and went a alert? How to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently go-mode doesn't support running goimports on a remote host (over tramp). If you just want to stop the error you can disable the `before-save-hook` that is invoking gofmt:

`(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'gofmt-before-save)`

Comment: Welcome, and thank you for your answer. So you actually want to use `remove-hook`, isn't it?

Comment: You could use remove-hook, or you could change the code you are using to not add it in the first place.